# IE Edge: SVG <use> relative path does not work

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, iframe

I have an issue when using SVG  in an iFrame in Internet Explorer Edge: the relative path is converted to an absolute one, with parent website as the base.

Here is a simple example:

**Parent website:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="./js/index.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Iframe (js/index.html):**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="./img1/icons1.svg#icon-view-close"></use>
        </svg>
        <img src="./img1/image1.jpg" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

**Network debugger:**
[image]

In the network debugger, instead of requesting "http://localhost:5500/js/img1/icons1.svg", Edge is requesting "http://localhost:5500/img1/icons1.svg".

The problem seems only to affect SVG use, because the JPG image's path is correctly interpreted: "http://localhost:5500/js/img1/image1.jpg"

Note: I tried converting the deprecated xlink:href to a simple href, but it does not change anything.

It works fine in every other browsers we tested: Chrome, FF and even IE 11, as we use the JS lib https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse

(I'm using Microsoft Edge 41.16299.785.0; on Windows 10.)

I would really appreciate any input in this matter! 
Thanks in advance for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters the same problem: I have found no other way to solve this issue than using another external library: [SVG4Everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) seems to do the trick for Edge, SVGs now load properly, everytime.